# Haskell or F# high throughput binary I/O

Tags: .net, haskell, f#, io

How good is the performance of binary I/O libraries in these two languages> I am contemplating about re-writing an ugly (yet very fast) C++ code that processes binary files of around 5-10GB using standard fread and fwrite functions. What slow-down factor should I expect for an optimized implementation in F# and Haskell?

EDIT:
here is the C implementation of counting zero-bytes (buffer allocated on heap).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 32*1024
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    char *buf;
    long i = 0, s = 0, l = 0;
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (!fp) {
        printf("Openning %s failed\n", argv[1]);
        return -1;
    }
    buf = (char *) malloc(SIZE);
    while (!feof(fp)) {
        l = fread(buf, 1, SIZE, fp);
        for (i = 0; i &lt l; ++i) {
            if (buf[i] == 0) {
                ++s;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", s);
    fclose(fp);
    free(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

The results:

```
$ gcc -O3 -o ioc io.c
$ ghc --make -O3 -o iohs io.hs
Linking iohs ...
$ time ./ioc 2.bin
462741044

real    0m16.171s
user    0m11.755s
sys     0m4.413s
$ time ./iohs 2.bin
4757708340

real    0m16.879s
user    0m14.093s
sys     0m2.783s
$ ls -lh 2.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1  14G Jan  4 10:05 2.bin
```

Comment: I'd like to see the rest of the code you tried to add in your edit. :-)

Comment: done. the C code prints the wrong result due to %d in printf (should be %qd I guess).

Comment: Thanks. Are you using the `B.count` function in the Haskell or a `fold`?

Comment: @user394460: "the C code prints the wrong result due to %d in printf (should be %qd I guess)". I think you'll need both to make `s` a `long long` and to print it using the format specified `%lld`.

Comment: I used the B.count version, which I think is chunk based.

Comment: The fold based version is about 2-3 times slower

Comment: Since `s` is a `long`, you should use `%ld` in the format string.  If you used `gcc -Wall`, it would tell you this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I blogged about this [here](http://flyingfrogblog.blogspot.com/2011/01/io-throughput-haskell-vs-f.html).

Comment: I'm impressed that F# is actually *faster* than Haskell for something... Even if it is file IO.

Comment: @Jon Harrop: Now, seriously: 1) I'm a .NET developer, so we are at the same side here. 2) Haskell has that *aura* of being the fastest functional language around, and that was what my comment was all about. But here are the results for both [Haskell](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/measurements.php?lang=ghc) and [F# Mono](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/measurements.php?lang=fsharp) on [The Computer Language Benchmark Game](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/) (and I don't know how accurate or up-to-date that benchmark is, but you asked for "citation"...)

Comment: @rsenna: "Haskell has that aura of being the fastest functional language around". LOL, no. Haskell is *notoriously slow*, often orders of magnitude slower than other languages.

Comment: @rsenna: "But here are the results for both Haskell and F# Mono on The Computer Language Benchmark Game". Half of the "Haskell" programs there are written in GHC's FFI using things like `malloc` precisely because Haskell is slow. The "F#" results are a consequence of Mono's awful performance.

Comment: @rsenna: On the other hand: idiomatic quicksort in Haskell was 6,000× slower than F# last I looked; Burrows-Wheeler Transform in Haskell was 10,000× slower in Haskell; Haskell's `Data.HashTable` is 26× slower than .NET's `Dictionary`... and so on. Haskell is many things but fast is not one of them.

Comment: @Jon Harrop: [citation needed]

Comment: @Daniel: `Data.HashTable` http://flyingfrogblog.blogspot.com/2010/07/haskells-hash-tables-revisited-part-2.html

Comment: @Daniel: For quicksort, take the code from here but replace the C++: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Why_Haskell_Matters

Comment: @Daniel: Replace the C++ with Sedgewick's from here: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/talks/QuicksortIsOptimal.pdf

Comment: Sorry, but after reading the comments, [I couldn't resist](http://xkcd.com/285/). :)

Comment: @Jon Harrop: about your [first link](http://groups.google.com/group/fa.haskell/msg/93179671e161c972), it seems to be about how slower is an implementation of the *Burrows-Wheeler Transform* when compared to **C++**. Not a thing about F# there, so I guess you still own us a citation! (Not that I really care about that - I'm just a imperative programmer, that was just trying to make you a *compliment* when I first got here, but I guess by being such a passive-aggressive person you haven't even noticed that...)

Comment: @rsenna: Burrows Wheeler in F# is as fast as the production C code in bzip2: http://flyingfrogblog.blogspot.com/2009/07/ocaml-vs-f-burrows-wheeler.html http://fsharpnews.blogspot.com/2009/08/optimizing-burrows-wheeler-transform.html

Comment: @rsenna: Make sure you benchmark against production C/C++ code and not the C++ code the Haskell guys cite that is 200× slower than the real thing. Let me know if there is anything else I can help with.

Comment: @Jon: Regarding your 'warning', given that the `length` function is defined for any `ByteString`, regardless of origin, how is it that it "looks up the file size"? Also, how is it relevant that portions of the Haskell API are coded in C? It's all machine code in the end anyway, right? Or was that comment intended as a bit of trivia?

Comment: @Daniel: "given that the length function is defined for any ByteString, regardless of origin, how is it that it "looks up the file size"?". ByteString divides the total file length (that it looks up) into chunks and prepares to load each chunk on-demand. Your code simply sums the lengths of the chunks without looking at their contents. In contrast, my original F# code was folding over each byte in each chunk. Hence your program has asymptotically lower time complexity: because it is a different algorithm and, in particular, one that is useless to the OP.

Comment: @Daniel: "how is it relevant that portions of the Haskell API are coded in C". The part of your benchmark that is playing the role of the OP's Haskell is written in C so your results are not representative of what the OP intends to do, they are misleading.

Comment: @Daniel: "It's all machine code in the end anyway, right?". That observation is of little use when trying to compare the efficiencies of solutions created using different tools.

Comment: @Jon: Please try to be reasonable. It makes no difference in what language the underlying function was written. The performance is the performance. The `ReadByte` function you're calling in your F# code was most likely written in C#. Does that mean your example is not representative of F# performance?

Comment: @Jon: "It's all machine code in the end anyway, right?" is a perfectly valid justification for the use of `memchr` inside `count`.  It does not break the abstraction in any way.  The _implementation_ of `count` is irrelevant:  The fact that he was able to use `count` without knowing or caring about its implementation is precisely the point of having a high-level language with an FFI:  He said what he meant in a simple high-level way, and the compiler and libraries conspired to implement it in a fast low-level way.  I don't know how that's not a good thing.

Comment: @Daniel: I am being very reasonable. The OP wants to rewrite code that is processing large files using `fread` from C++ to Haskell or F#. That means the data processing must be done in Haskell/F# for the benchmark to be representative but it can call low-level IO as the C++ already does. Therefore, you can use `ByteString` to do the IO but you must do the processing in Haskell/F#. If you also do the processing in C by choosing a task for which there happens to be a standard library function then your results are not representative of general IO throughput but, rather, of that special case.

Comment: @mokus: "It does not break the abstraction in any way... I don't know how that's not a good thing.". Having that function at your disposal is a good thing. Pretending that it is representative of Haskell's IO throughput for the general purpose processing of large files is a bad thing.

Comment: @Jon - With my out of date Mono system Haskell was way ahead, but I'll update with a link to results for that platform when I've got a supported version of Mono running.  (My very rough version of your test scripts: https://bitbucket.org/killerswan/functionalio/src.)

A word of warning: anyone using Mono in Ubuntu (as I have just tested) is way out of date: 2.6.7.  And GHC 6.12.1 may also be out of date: GHC 7 has a spiffy new IO manager...

Comment: @Kevin: That's interesting. If there's one thing I thought Mono might have done well it'd be IO. My Haskell Platform on Windows is on GHC 6.12.3 but it doesn't seem much different from GHC 6.12.1, although I don't exactly give it a lot of exercise.

Comment: @Jon, some up-to-date results: on Ubuntu and considering Mono 2.8.2, F# is not as fast, but at least I did get a HUGE improvement going from Mono 2.6.7 to 2.8.2.  (http://log.kevincantu.org/2011/01/f-vs-haskell-vs-go-or-upgrade-mono.html)

Answer (score 9):

Haskell using *lazy* ByteString-based IO, with a "binary" parser should be around the same performance as C code doing the same job, on the same data types.

The key packages to be aware of:

- [bytestring](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring)
- [binary](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary)

Comment: @Jon, according to your current results (0:47 GMT) it looks like lazy ByteString and .NET are pretty much equivalent.  That is, if your timings are from a single run of each program.

Comment: my initial testing shows that C (fread/fwrite) and lazy ByteString perform indeed similarly.

Comment: user394460: On what platform(s)?

Comment: on rhel-x86_64-5.2/gcc 4.3.2, I tested the zero byte-count example that Daniel provided against a simple C code I wrote. I believe ByteString uses 32K defaultChunkSize, so that's what I used in C as well.

Comment: This is really the best answer. Any modern language with a decent FFI and decent libraries should be able to do straightforward IO with a bound imposed by hardware limitations. This was one of the results fairly demonstrated by Tim Bray's widefinder benchmark.

Comment: @sclv: You've just shifted the question to "are they decent"? And, according to Daniel's result that the built-in `count` is several times faster than either native Haskell or F#, they are not decent.

Comment: no. i said they can do IO with a bound imposed by hardware limitations. Which they can. Once the file is read, there's a cost to marshalling individual byte values out. Raw C naturally doesn't pay that cost, which in this simple case is unnecessary overhead. Note that this raw c does *not* use memchr by the way, or glibc at all. It is a straightforward loop: http://darcs.haskell.org/bytestring/cbits/fpstring.c

Comment: @sclv: Being able to load the file into an array efficiently is of no practical value if you cannot then read the data out of the array efficiently in order to process it. Redefining IO as getting the data off the platter and into the HDD's cache is equally useless...

Answer (score 8):

Considering that this post entails:

- Haskell
- code optimizations
- performance benchmarks

...it's safe to say that I'm in way over my head. Nevertheless, I always learn something when I get in over my head, so here goes.

I went spelunking around the `Data.ByteString.Lazy.*` Haskell modules via [Hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle/) and found the [length](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/latest/doc/html/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#v%3alength) function for measuring the length of a lazy ByteString. It is implemented thus:

```
length :: ByteString -> Int64
length cs = foldlChunks (\n c -> n + fromIntegral (S.length c)) 0 cs
```

Hmm. Jon did say that "...Folding over **chunks** of file in the F# is a major part of why it is fast..." (my emphasis). And this `length` function appears to be implemented using a chunky fold as well. So it appears that this function is much more of an 'apples to apples' comparison to Jon's F# code.

Does it make a difference in practice? I compared Jon's example to the following:

```
import System
import Data.List
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as B

main =
    getArgs
    >>= B.readFile . Data.List.head
    >>= print . B.length
```

Jon's Haskell example on my machine for a 1.2 GB file: **10.5s**

The 'chunky' version: **1.1s**

The 'chunky' version of the Haskell code is nearly **ten times** faster. Which suggests that it is probably multiple times faster than Jon's optimized F# code.

**EDIT**

While I don't necessarily completely agree with Jon's criticisms of my example, I would like to make it as impeachable as possible. As such, I have profiled the following code:

```
import System
import Data.List
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as B

main =
    getArgs
    >>= B.readFile . Data.List.head
    >>= print . B.count 0
```

This code loads the contents of the target file into a ByteString and then 'counts' each occurence of a 0-value byte. Unless I'm missing something, this program must load and evaluate each byte of the target file.

The above program runs consistently about 4x faster than the latest fastest Haskell program submitted by Jon, copied here for reference (in case it is updated):

```
import System
import Data.Int
import Data.List
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as B

main =
    getArgs
    >>= B.readFile . Data.List.head
    >>= print . B.foldl (\n c -> n + 1) (0 :: Data.Int.Int64)
```

Comment: Good job comparing apples to apples -- not necessarily jdh's strength :-)

Comment: @Daniel: My programs all consider the input byte-by-byte. Yours does not.

Comment: Also too lazy to check but two other issues in jdh's code -- the use of char8 rather than plain bytestring requires lots and lots of (cheap, individually) calls to w2c, which as I recall does give a tiny performance hit. And I'd be curious is foldr doesn't give better results than foldl for lazy data.

Comment: Since I missed the intervening exchange, I'd suggest trying both the right fold and using plain rather than char8 bytestrings and seeing how far you get with those two choices alone.

Comment: @sclv: I checked the folds and presented the fastest one. I believe `foldl` over `ByteString` is strict. IIRC, `foldr` incurs O(n) heap size in this case. I'm trying plain without `Char8` now...

Comment: @Daniel: Jon's edited his post so it's probably more clear now, but AFAICT his on-demand programs were/are equivalent.

Comment: @sclv, for me `foldl` is faster (and it's equivalent to `foldl'`).

Comment: @sclv: I switched from `Char8` to plain `ByteString` in the Haskell and it isn't significantly faster, although the variance is now down from 20% to just 5% between the languages.

Comment: @Jon: at this point I would suggest that the variance is due more to the vagaries of I/O than any significant difference between generated code (particularly if you're only using one run for a data point).  I doubt the difference between Char8 and plain ByteString is that significant.

Comment: @John: I'm using best-of-three and the variance between the three is comparable to the variance between the languages which, I agree, will be due to the IO. What exactly *is* the difference between plain and `Char8`?

Comment: @Daniel: The docs you cite even explain that `length` is a different algorithm because it cites asymptotic time complexity of *O(n/c)* and, therefore, it cannot be considering the input byte-by-byte. Please correct or delete your answer.

Comment: In order to ensure that all bytes from the input file are considered, whilst still using a 'chunky' API, I decided to use `B.maximum` (vs. `B.length`). Well, I don't trust the result. It was too fast. What's going on? Is the maximum function smart enough to not consider values beyond 255?

Comment: @Jon: Delete my answer?! Considering the description of your program, and I quote "I wrote the following Haskell program to read a file using the eager ByteString and then accumulate its length using a fold", is my program is not doing exactly that?

Comment: @Daniel: Your program is doing neither what the question requires nor what my code was doing. If you're going to just read the length and ignore the contents (which is absolutely not what my buffer was doing) at least have the decency to state as much instead of trying to pretend your results have anything to do with IO throughput.

Comment: @Jon Regardless of your point of view, I think it can be considered common courtesy to give someone an opportunity to update their own post without prompting.

Comment: @Daniel: Absolutely. I gave you the time since my first comment which, according to Stack Overflow, was 2 hours during which you found the time to comment twice but still did not correct your answer.

Comment: @Jon A couple of your edits might have been worth keeping, but certainly not all of them. I'm not going to cherry-pick, so I rolled your edit back completely.

Comment: @Jon - Plain bytestrings are a buffer of `Word8`s.  The `Char8` version uses the same buffer but calls `w2c` (ANSII conversion of Word8 to Char) on each element.  For the folds in your code samples, the individual elements aren't ever evaluated, so this conversion doesn't actually happen.  By my tests the Char versions are slightly slower, so there's probably some overhead for creating the thunk.

Comment: @Daniel: as `B.maximum` returns a `Word8`, I would expect it to stop when it reaches 255.

Comment: @John: Thanks for the explanation. I changed my code to XOR the bytes, so every one is evaluated, and the performance is not significantly different. I assumed the strict `foldl` would have been forcing the evaluation of each byte?

Comment: @Jon: not quite.  The function you pass to `foldl` is `\n c -> n+1`.  This function may build up a large thunk of the form `(((n+1)+1)+1) ...` which would be evaluated when you print the fold result.  The strict `foldl'` reduces its output at each step, preventing this thunk from accumulating.  GHC notices not to build the thunk in this case so it doesn't make a difference; this expression would certainly blow the stack otherwise.  The `c` is never used, which is what I meant (it doesn't need to be evaluated as a `Char`, but it's probably loaded anyway, check core to be sure).

Comment: @JonH there are multiple flags on this post, FYI -- I strongly advise you to moderate your rhetoric on these topics because I'm getting tired of the trail of mod flags you're leaving behind.

Comment: @Daniel: "The above program runs consistently about 4x faster than the latest fastest Haskell program submitted by Jon". I cannot reproduce your result. On this machine, the performance difference is insignificant (smaller than the variance). Has anyone else reproduced this? Daniel, what is your setup?

Comment: @Jon GHC v6.12.3 running on Win7 64-bit, 8 GB ram, Intel Core Duo @ 2.93 GHz. Compiled both with the same flags. I notice the difference in timings diminishes with file size: On a 'small' file (1.2 GB), your code runs about 9.5s. My code runs about 2.5s. On a large file (16.3 GB) your code ran 420s. My code ran 350s.

Comment: @Daniel: You might want to note the enormous discrepancy between what you claim in your answer and your actual results. 420 vs 350 seconds is not a factor of four...

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: If you have any specific criticisms, I am more than happy to discuss. If you expect me to pander to fanboys and let their misinformation slide, I won't.

Comment: @Jon It _is_ about 4x faster up to a certain (quite large) size. I'm assuming it isn't coincidence that the size at which that starts to happen is close to the total memory capacity of this machine.